# Issue running a lambda two times in sequence from Airflow in AWS

Tags: python, aws-lambda, airflow, sequence

I am very new to Airflow. I have a single lambda function that needs to be executed two times in sequence. I am passing the payload from dag file (say date), based on this date my lambda will fetch the records from an API.

The lambda works fine when testing it manually for different dates, but when I create a dag file to invoke them in sequence, the second lambda is executed more than once. For this task, second time execution starts even before the first execution of lambda is complete.

I am not using any retries in my dag, not sure if the issue is at the lambda end or dag end or if anything configuration related.

No errors noted at dag, but the lambda log shows the multiple invocation of the second task.

Any help with this appreciated!

Thanks!

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import boto3
import json
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


args = { 'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': days_ago(1), 'catchup': False, 'provide_context': True }
#50 13 * * *
dag = DAG( 'my_dag', schedule_interval = None, default_args = args )

def lambda1_trigger(ds,**kwargs):
    pld =json.dumps({"date":"27/06/2022"})
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name=aws_region,aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    response_1 = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='my_lambda_function',InvocationType='RequestResponse',Payload = pld)
    print('Response--->', response_1)

def lambda2_trigger(ds,**kwargs):
    pld =json.dumps({"date":"28/06/2022"})
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name=aws_region,aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    response_1 = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='my_lambda_function',InvocationType='RequestResponse',Payload = pld)
    print('Response--->', response_1)

start = DummyOperator(task_aid='Begin_execution', dag=dag)
invoke_lambda1 = PythonOperator( task_id="task1", python_callable=lambda1_trigger, provide_context=True,execution_timeout=datetime.timedelta(hours=1), dag=dag)
invoke_lambda2 = PythonOperator( task_id="task2", python_callable=lambda2_trigger, provide_context=True,execution_timeout=datetime.timedelta(hours=1), dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='stop_execution', dag=dag)

start >> invoke_lambda1 >> invoke_lambda2 >> end`
```

Comment: can you share your dag?

Comment: sure, shared my dag as above.

Comment: @mvs, you found any solution? I face same thing